# Apply gravity between two or more objects in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, html5-canvas

I was creating something like a 2d gravity simulator, just for fun, and noticed that I'm a complete idiot in terms of math. I just can't get the gravity to work.

I've tried following the instructions found [**here**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17620/equation-to-make-small-number-big-and-big-number-small-gravity) but it looks weird and when the distance reaches zero, it goes completely buggy. If I add `1` to the distance as recommended in the question, all objects go upper left. I've even tried not modifying gravity when distances reach zero, but this doesn't change the behavior.

[image: demonstration of the problem]

**Here's the algorithm I'm using to apply gravity:**

```
var distX = obj1.x - obj2.x,
    distY = obj1.y - obj2.y;
if (obj1 != obj2) {
    if (distY != 0) {
        obj1.vy += -(1 / (distY));
    }
    if (distX != 0) {
        obj1.vx += -(1 / (distX));
    }
}
```

I've tried using other algorithms too, but most of them don't care for the distance between objects.

*Note that I want the gravity to affect distant objects less than closer objects.*

[image: JSFiddle]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of solving any equations we could use an approximation. `dv/dt = G*M*m/r^2`, but for small t we could use the approximation `Δv = (G*M*m/r^2)*Δt`.

When the objects collide I have implemented perfectly inelastic collision (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision#Perfectly_inelastic_collision)). This prevents the distance between two objects from being to small and therefore the maximum force is limited.

I also moved the part of the code where the object's position is changed to a separate loop, so the forces calculated for obj1 and obj2 are equal in size.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fposgc1t/8/)

```
function tick() {
   allObjs.forEach(function (obj1) {
      allObjs.forEach(function (obj2) {
         var diffX = obj2.x - obj1.x,
         var diffY = obj2.y - obj1.y;
         var distSquare = diffX*diffX + diffY*diffY
         var dist = Math.sqrt(distSquare);
         if (obj1 != obj2) {
            if (dist > obj1.w/2 + obj2.w/2) {
               //If you add mass to the objects change to obj2.mass
               //instead of 50
               var totalForce = 50/distSquare;
               obj1.vx += totalForce * diffX / dist;
               obj1.vy += totalForce * diffY / dist;
            } else {
               //Collision has occurred
               //If you add mass to the objects change to
               //tempX = (obj1.mass*obj1.vx + obj2.mass*obj2.vx)/(obj1.mass+
               //obj2.mass);
               //tempY = (obj1.mass*obj1.vy + obj2.mass*obj2.vy)/(obj1.mass+
               //obj2.mass);
               var tempX = (obj1.vx + obj2.vx)/2;
               var tempY = (obj1.vy + obj2.vy)/2;
               obj1.vx = tempX; obj2.vx = tempX;
               obj1.vy = tempY; obj2.vy = tempY;
             }
          }
       });
   });

   allObjs.forEach(function (obj1) {
      obj1.x += obj1.vx / 25;
      obj1.y += obj1.vy / 25;
   });
   stage.update();
}
```

Comment: Math.pow is a slow way to square a number. Multiplying by itself is quicker. Math.hypot(double x, double y) might be the most accurate.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Is there any explanation why Math.pow is slow?

Comment: Thank you a lot, works flawlessly. I'll spend a good time learning more about physics and the changes you've made. Collision detection was a good way of preventing infinite force. :)

Comment: You are welcome! However, you should improve the collision detection. If an object moves to fast it might tunnel trough another object.

Comment: It mainly designed for non-integer powers and uses an algorithm based on logs.

Comment: @Afsa No problem, I'll detect collisions by checking the last and current object's positions.

Comment: Note that instead of doing what your comment says on line 57 of your fiddle (`//If you add mass to the objects change to obj1.mass * obj2.mass instead of 50`) I'm using `var totalForce = (obj2.mass)/distSquare;` so objects with more mass will not be over atracted by objects with less mass.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. What I wrote is the formula for force, but since `F=ma` one mass cancels out.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
                    var distX = obj1.x - obj2.x,
                        distY = obj1.y - obj2.y;
                    var rsq = distX *distX + distY * distY;
                    var r = Math.sqrt(rsq);
                    var F = 50 / rsq;        // constant chosen to be pleasing
                    var rhat_x = distX / r;
                    var rhat_y = distY / r;
                    var Fx = F * rhat_x;
                    var Fy = F * rhat_y;

                    obj1.vx += -Fx;
                    obj1.vy += -Fy;
                    obj2.vx += Fx;
                    obj2.vy += Fy;
```

This is very basic, its not taking mass into account its using the simplest possible way of solving the equations you should really use something like 5th order Runga-Kutta w/ error correction. But it does use the formula for gravitational

```
 F = - G m1 m2 / r^2
```

where G is the universal gravitational constant, m1 m2 are the two masses (I've all of these to 1!) r^2 is the square of the distance between the objects. The force is in the direction to the other object, let this be a unit vector `rhat` so the vector version of the force, using 1 for the constants

```
 F = - ( 1 / r^2 ) rhat
```

The above gives reasonable results it you start out with

```
createPlanet(50, 200, 2, 0, 1);         
createPlanet(400, 200, 2, 0, -1);
```

you have to take care that the two planets don't get too close or the acceleration goes off to infinity and the velocities get too big.

While playing around I tried

```
var distX = obj1.x - obj2.x,
    distY = obj1.y - obj2.y;
var rsq = distX *distX + distY * distY; // square of the distance
var r = Math.sqrt(rsq);
var Fx = distX / r;
var Fy = distY / r;
obj1.vx += -Fx;
obj1.vy += -Fy;
obj2.vx += Fx;
obj2.vy += Fy;
```

which gives pleasing but physically incorrect results.

Answer (score -1):

Newton's equations of motion `F = ma` need to be solved here.  You are not doing anything like that in your code.  No wonder it isn't matching your intuition.

It would help to understand the physics.

This is a *vector* equation.  The force is gravity, which follows an inverse distance squared law.

You also know how acceleration, velocity, and displacement are related.  You have to know calculus.

For your 2D world, that means six equations for each body in the problem.  Two bodies means 12 coupled equations.

Solving these equations means integrating all those coupled ordinary differential equations in time.  You'll need to know something about numerical methods (e.g. Runga-Kutta 5th order integration w/ error correction).

You'd have a lot to learn to write such a thing yourself.  I'd recommend looking into a JavaScript physics library like Box2D or something else that Google might [find](https://www.google.com/search?q=2d%20gravity%20javascript%20library&oq=2d%20gravity%20javascript%20library&aqs=chrome..69i57.6143j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Dude, you've got to learn something about physics or use a library by someone else who does.  I'd search for that library.  I don't think you're up for writing such a thing.  It's a common question on SO.  See what you find here first.

Comment: F=ma ?? you need http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation